# htaccess redirect subfolder to another without using root htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been searching all day for a solution.

So a friend of my used the horrible web builder to build a basic website in the root directory. For whatever reason, web builder sticks its files in a /site subfolder and it holds the root htaccess hostage. Any changes to web builder overwrite the htaccess.

Now, she has two subfolders. sub1 and sub2. We need to get any attempt to access sub1 to redirect to sub2. I am used to doing this by putting the following code in the root htaccess:

```
# Enable rewriting.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?sub1/(.*)$ /sub2/$1 [R,L]
```

But as said, the web builder will erase all of that any time she publishes any changes. I put a new htaccess file in sub1 with the following text:

```
Redirect 302 / http://example.com/sub2
```

That redirected the subfolder, but not correctly. It actually redirected to http//example.com/sub2sub1 for some reason that I can't figure out.

I feel like the solution is right in my face but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RedirectMatch Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).

```
RedirectMatch 302 /sub1/(.*) /sub2/$1
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect! It even carries over the file structure (so that sub1/index.php=string directs to sub2/index.php=string).